# Retrieve data from custom object on Visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce, custom-object, sosl

I have created a custom object which contains multiple fields that I want to be able to show on a Visualforce page. From the discussion I've had with another developer it was recommended that I use a utility class and just reference that from the standard class. Here's what I've got.

**Utility class**

```
public without sharing class pkb_content_Utility {
  public PKB_Content__c pos{get;set;}
  public pkb_Controller() {
    pos = [SELECT Home_Forum__c FROM PKB_Content__c];
  }
}
```

While I only reference Home_Forum__c, there are multiple other fields I need to reference as well but I am unsure of the best way to do this.

**Main controller class**

```
pos = pkb_content_Utility.pkb_Controller();
```

**Visualforce code**

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" standardController="KnowledgeArticle" extensions="pkb_Controller">
  <apex:outputText value="{!pos.Home_Forum__c}"/>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `ApexPages.StandardController sc` as a constructor argument (that can be used to get a reference the `KnowledgeArticle` if that is needed) makes the class fit the controller extension pattern that it looks like you are aiming for based on your page:

```
public without sharing class PkbContentController {
      public PKB_Content__c pos {get;set;}
      public PkbContentController(ApexPages.StandardController sc) {
          // Add all the other fields you need here instead of ...
          pos = [SELECT Home_Forum__c, ... FROM PKB_Content__c limit 1];
      }
}
```

This pattern "mixes in" the controller extension with the standard controller so your page can reference both; in your example you are only referencing the controller extension field:

```
<apex:page showHeader="false"
        standardController="KnowledgeArticle"
        extensions="PkbContentController">
    <apex:outputText value="{!pos.Home_Forum__c}"/>
    <!-- Output more fields here -->
</apex:page>
```

See e.g. the [Building a Controller Extension](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_controller_extension.htm) documentation for more information.